# I want to get a tattoo but I need help with translation. How would you say “for myself” in Latin? Would you say “pro/per ego/memet”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, motto, new-latin

I want to get a tattoo but I need help with translation. How would you say “for myself” in Latin? Would you say “pro/per ego/memet”?

Comment: What is this supposed to mean? There is a big difference between, for example, “thinking for myself” and “a gift for myself,” etc. Very simply, you could say *pro me* (or *pro me ipso/ipsa*).

Comment: It’s supposed to be “for myself” as in everything I do I do for myself. If that makes sense.